# IE-10 and Below: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var xhr = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", getPwdExpireNotificationUrlv2);
xhr.onload = function() { resolve(xhr.responseText);}
xhr.onerror = function() { reject(xhr.statusText);}
xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {xhr.send();};
xhr.send();
```

While making multiple similar requests(like above) by using javascript "Promise.all".

Comment: Any way you could post more of your code?

Comment: I found that the issue is not with this code, actually the error is coming due to some other reason and I found that In my page jQuery is loaded more than once with different-different versions..may be this is the root cause. I have to debug more..